# Why is there a gap between top titlerule line and the contents of chapter and section? Also why is the thickness of these rules not equal in Chapter?

Tags: formatting, titlesec, geometry, rules, parskip

I am attempting to learn the commands associated with the titlesec package. It appears that the `parskip` value is added before the chapter/section content. As a result, the content is not vertically centered between the two titlerules. I have used the following code and am using `TeXstudio` and `MiKTeX`.
(Also, why is the thickness of the titlerule before and after the chapter content not equal even though I set it to be 1ex?)

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[showframe, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
%\usepackage[skip=40pt]{parskip}
\setlength{\parskip}{40pt}
\setlength{\topskip}{0pt}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}{{\titlerule[1ex]}\Huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{}[{\titlerule[1ex]}]

\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{40pt}

\titleformat{\section}{\titlerule\LARGE\bfseries}{\thesection}{20pt}{}[\titlerule]

\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{70pt}{40pt}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}

    \chapter{Introduction One}

    \section{Section One}

    \kant[1-4]

    \section{Section Two}

    \kant[2-3]

    \subsection{Subsection One}

    \kant[5-6]

    \section{Section Three}

    \kant[8-11]

    \subsection{Subsection one}

    \kant[12]

    \subsubsection{Subsubsection one}

    \kant[13]

\end{document}
```

[image: Image Generated by code]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose a better answer will come from people who actually use `titlesec` *and* have read its documentation.

- I compensate preemptively the parskip added space
- As for the distinct width it is because you used the `ex` unit which depends on the font. So I moved the fontsize (and series) change earlier.
- `\endgraf` is because `\titleformat` refuses `\par` in the arguments

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[showframe, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
%\usepackage[skip=40pt]{parskip}
\setlength{\parskip}{40pt}
\setlength{\topskip}{0pt}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}{\Huge\bfseries\titlerule[1ex]\endgraf\vskip-\parskip}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{}[{\titlerule[1ex]}]

\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{40pt}

\titleformat{\section}{\titlerule\LARGE\bfseries\endgraf\vskip-\parskip}{\thesection}{20pt}{}[\titlerule]

\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{70pt}{40pt}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}

    \chapter{Introduction One}

    \section{Section One}

    \kant[1-4]

    \section{Section Two}

    \kant[2-3]

    \subsection{Subsection One}

    \kant[5-6]

    \section{Section Three}

    \kant[8-11]

    \subsection{Subsection one}

    \kant[12]

    \subsubsection{Subsubsection one}

    \kant[13]

\end{document}
```

[image: use of titleformat with titlerule]